Google Calendar Integration: Storing Manager's Token Efficiently
I am working on a project where I need to integrate Google Calendar for event management. The objective is as follows:

Allow a manager to create events, which will then be displayed on a web application.
Enable users to join those events and view them on their own calendar within the application.

In terms of integrating Google Calendar, I need to manage the manager’s calendar token. However, I’m uncertain about the most efficient way to handle this. Specifically:

Should I store the manager’s calendar token in the database, or is there a more efficient approach?
Is it necessary to save the token for each event, or can it be stored just once for the manager?

I've considered saving the token once for the manager, but I want to confirm if this is the best approach before proceeding
